# How to display the details of the most frequently referenced entry

Tags: sql, oracle, count, filtering

So I have a table which is for tickets within an IT helpdesk. Each Ticket "*ID_TICKET*" is related to a specific fault and has an associated computer "*SERIAL_NO_COMPUTER*".

I want to be able to count the number of faults connected with each computer and then display the details of each individual fault "*PROBLEM_DESCRIPTION*" for the computer with the most faults.

I have created the below to tally the number of faults associated with each machine:

```
SELECT SERIAL_NO_COMPUTER, COUNT(*) AS OCCURANCES
FROM TICKET 
GROUP BY SERIAL_NO_COMPUTER 
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC;
```

This provides me with the computer with the most reported faults but I am unsure how to then produce the details for each problem using only one statement.

Comment: Could you edit your question and share some simple data and the expected output ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to gather information of the computer with the most reported faults, instead of aggregating, you can use:

- a window function inside the `ORDER BY` clause, that changes the order of your records based on the count of records.
- [`FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS WITH TIES`](https://www.oracletutorial.com/oracle-basics/oracle-fetch/), to gather the one row tied on the highest count (this clause takes into consideration the `ORDER BY` clause).

```
SELECT TICKET.*
FROM TICKET 
ORDER BY COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY SERIAL_NO_COMPUTER) DESC 
FETCH NEXT 1 ROW WITH TIES
```

If two pcs have the same amount of maximum faults, this query should give you records from both pcs. If you instead want just records from one pc only, you need to add a further column to order on inside the `ORDER BY` clause (for example the pc serial).

```
SELECT TICKET.*
FROM TICKET 
ORDER BY COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY SERIAL_NO_COMPUTER) DESC, SERIAL_NO_COMPUTER
FETCH NEXT 1 ROW WITH TIES
```

Comment: I was about to write the same answer. If a particular order is desired, e.g. show the tickets for the most faulty computer(s) ordered by ticket date, then select from this query and add the desired `ORDER BY` clause.

Comment: Agree. I'm not sure about adding the ticket date in the `ORDER BY` clause, as the risk would be that the fetch recovers only one record instead of many belonging to the same pc (specifically depending on the OP's data), but the idea of using further fields (computed and non) is definitely needed to untie multiple pcs.

Comment: Yep, I was thinking along the lines of `WITH most_faulty AS ( <your query> ) SELECT FROM most_faulty ORDER BY serial_no_computer, ticket_date;`